# Parallelization of Quicksort in C

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, quicksort

For an assignment I got a finished functional sequential version of a quicksort program in C, but now I need to speed it up with parallelization with the use of threads. The modified program below **is sorting** and are using the threads (using >100% CPU), but it takes longer now than before when executing in sequential.

The way this program is suppose to work, is that when the 8th thread has been terminated, the program should now instead continue to execute the rest of the program sequential.

I know maybe this is not the optional way when optimizing with threads, but that's how this program should work. I guess there has something to do with the `pthread_join`, but I tried to move it, but that makes no difference, or even worse sometimes.

*Note, I did include the initializing of the array here, because it's not relevant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define THREADS 8
#define KILO (1024)
#define MEGA (1024*1024) //1 048 576
#define MAX_ITEMS (64 *MEGA) //67 108 864
#define swap(v, a, b) {unsigned tmp; tmp=v[a]; v[a]=v[b]; v[b]=tmp;}

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int *v; 
int global_thread = 1; //Starts at 1, because the thread from main is the first

struct threadArgs 
{
    int low;
    int high;
};

static int partition(int *v, int low, int high, int pivot_index)
{
    if (pivot_index != low)
        swap(v, low, pivot_index);

    pivot_index = low;
    low++;

    while (low <= high) 
    {
        if (v[low] <= v[pivot_index]) 
            low++;
        else if (v[high] > v[pivot_index])
            high--;
        else
            swap(v, low, high);
    }
    
    if (high != pivot_index)
        swap(v, pivot_index, high);

    return high;
}

void* quick_sort(void* arguments)
{
    struct threadArgs* parent = (struct threadArgs*) arguments;
    pthread_t child;
    
    struct threadArgs* child_thread;
    child_thread =  malloc(sizeof(struct threadArgs));    
    
    int pivot_index;

    int low = parent->low;
    int high = parent->high;

    if (low >= high)
        return NULL;

    pivot_index = (low + high) / 2;
    pivot_index = partition(v, low, high, pivot_index);
    
    if(global_thread < THREADS) //should only create 7 new threads, 1 is already from main
    {
        if(pivot_index < high) //child: right side
        {
            child_thread->low = pivot_index +1;
            child_thread->high = high;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            global_thread++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            
            pthread_create(&child, NULL, quick_sort, (void*) child_thread);
        }
        if(low < pivot_index) //parent: left side,
        {
            parent->low = low;
            parent->high = pivot_index - 1;
            quick_sort((void*) parent);
        }
        pthread_join(child, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        if (low < pivot_index) //left side sequential
        {
            parent->low = low;
            parent->high = pivot_index - 1;
            quick_sort((void*) parent);
        }
        if (pivot_index < high) //right side sequential
        {
            parent->low = pivot_index +1;
            parent->high = high;
            quick_sort((void*) parent);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    init_array();

    struct threadArgs* args; // main thread
    args =  malloc(sizeof(struct threadArgs));
    args->low = 0;
    args->high = MAX_ITEMS - 1;

    quick_sort((void *)args);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    free(args);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `init_array()` ?

Comment: This code has a race condition and will create more than the requested number of threads; the `if (thread_count < THREADS)` test is separated from the `thread_count++` statement. Not sure how much this matters, but it could. Still looking.

Comment: How large an array are you sorting?  Multithreading incurs substantial overhead, and you need each thread to do a fair amount of work just to break even relative to serial code.  If your input is too small then there may not be enough work to make multithreading worthwhile.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The code shows 64M items, I'm testing with 100M items, but it mostly take the same amount of time on a 32-core machine so I suspect the OP is right to ask the question.

Comment: And how many cores does your machine have? It is not useful performance-wise to use more threads than you have available cores.

Comment: Chop up the data into multiple [L1 cache size] chunks, queue up the chunks, (well, pointer to struct containing chunk pointer, length, callback, error string etc), to [2*number of cores] pool threads that are waiting on a producer-consumer queue.  Have the pool threads quicksort each chunk.  When all chunks are quicksorted, mergesort them.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a serious memory leak: every call to `quick_sort()` allocates memory for a child thread's arguments, even if it does not ultimately start a new child thread, and none of that memory is ever freed.  `malloc()` is relatively expensive, and depending on your implementation, it may acquire a lock, thus creating a bottleneck.

Your code has a data race: `quick_sort()` reads shared variable `global_threads` outside the protection of a mutex or other synchronization object, and that variable is also modified by some of your threads.  The resulting behavior is therefore undefined.

Your code has a flaw in that the `global_thread < THREADS` branch of your `quick_sort()` function only conditionally starts a new thread, but unconditionally tries to join one.  If no child thread was started then the join attempt will produce undefined behavior on account of reading the value of variable `child` while it is indeterminate.  That would be unlikely to happen in practice with random data, however.

Suggestions:

1. move the `malloc()` call so that you allocate only in the event that you are actually going to create a new thread.  Since the amount per allocation is small and the number of allocations will then be small, you can probably get away with continuing to allow that memory to leak, but it would be better to free it after joining the child.
2. Change strategy for how you decide whether to start a child thread.  For example, track the recursion depth, and launch a new child only a shallow depth (two or three levels).  You then do not need a shared variable or mutex, just an additional member in `struct threadArgs`.
3. Make sure not to try to join a child thread when you have not launched one.

Implementation is left as an exercise, but my own implementation of those fixes yielded significant single-thread performance improvement and exhibited reasonable (but not great) speedup from adding more threads: about 30% speedup with two threads, and a bit more than 50% with four.

Comment: I saw that too. The `malloc()` can be dispensed with entirely by just creating a stack-based variable, allowing it to go out of scope after the left and right branches complete.

Comment: Also, one can decide not to bother with launching a thread if the # of items in the partition is below a certain number (say, 1000 items), where threading overhead would dominate.

Comment: Thank you! I works now when I changed where the malloc is done, and adding `free(child_thread)`